# Android studio: ResourceBundle [messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name messages, locale en_US

Tags: android, spring, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to run the project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-android-samples/tree/master/spring-android-basic-auth on android studio.
I have imported the server and client projects separately and am running the server on the terminal using:

```
gradlew build bootRun
```

I am running the client directly from android studio on an avd and when I apply the correct username password, I get 404 not found with the error:

> ResourceBundle [messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base 
>   name messages, locale en_US

I am guessing I need to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743433/resourcebundle-messages-not-found-for-messagesource-cant-find-bundle-for-bas) but am not sure how to do it in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I was trying to access the resource from an invalid directory